# Managing Lunar Vim (lvim) config.lua by separating it in different files

Tags: lua, neovim, lunarvim

Trying to write config.lua for lvim that wiil be separated in different files? that will be included in `config.lua` with `require('<package>')`. Everything works if i try i in `.config/lvim/` directory, but i get below message, when i run lvim in different directory.

```
21:43:43 [WARN ] lvim: "Invalid configuration: /home/axr/.config/lvim/config.lua:6: module 'base/search' not found:\n\t
no field package.preload['base/search']\n\tno file './base/search.lua'\n\tno file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/base/s
earch.lua'\n\tno file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/base/search.lua'\n\tno file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/base/search/init.
lua'\n\tno file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/base/search.lua'\n\tno file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/base/search/init.lua'\n\tno file '.
/base/search.so'\n\tno file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/base/search.so'\n\tno file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/base/search.so'\n\tno
file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'" file="init.lua", line=49
```

Tried to replace `/` with `.`, nothing changed.
Checked runtimepath, `.config/lvim/` was there.
Tried to replace relative path in `require(<path>)` with full path.

GitHub repository with files and comments: https://github.com/SATANalexander666/lvim-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/.config/lvim` must be created folder named `/lua` and all folders required in main `config.lua` must be moved to this folder, however path to required folders shouldn't be changed. Example: `require('base.search')`, while actual path is `/.config/lvim/lua/base/search.lua`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `/` or `\\` in `require()`
Only use the `.` for entering a folder.
Using `nvim` the `.config/nvim/lua` folder has to be created manually.
After that it is easy doing to require Lua files.

Example

```
.config/nvim/init.vim # file
.config/nvim/lua/config.lua # file
.config/nvim/lua/base # folder
.config/nvim/lua/keys # folder
.config/nvim/lua/plugins/core # folder
.config/nvim/lua/plugins/packer # folder
```

Content of init.vim

```
lua require("config")
```

Will be appended/finished to:  `lua/config.lua`
Refer nvim' help: `:help lua-package-path`

Content of config.lua

```
-- base
require('base.search') -- Search configs
require('base.indents') -- Indentation configs
require('base.visual') -- GUI configs
require('base.other')
-- keys
require('keys.alias') -- Shortcuts and incapsulation
require('keys.main') -- Keys for built-in features
require('keys.plugins') -- Keys for plugged features
-- plugins
require('plugins.core.use') -- Buil-in plugins that are being used
require('plugins.core.config') -- Configs for built-in plugins
require('plugins.packer.use') -- Packer pluggins that are being used
require('plugins.packer.config') -- Configs for packer plugins
```

The dot will be used to enter the folder(s)  (Linux & Windows)
Refer nvim' help: `:help lua-require`